# Analytical metric for comparing average run times?

Tags: data-analysis

I have a list of scripts and how long they take on average:

```
const averageRunTime = [
  srt_id:1, avg:8,    //  8 seconds
  srt_id:2, avg:600,  // 10 minutes
  srt_id:3, avg:3600  //  1 hour
]
```

So the first script typically runs in 8 seconds, the second takes about 10 minutes, and the 3rd about an hour.

And here are some run times:

```
const runs = [
  {id:1, srt_id:1, run_time:  320},  //  5 minutes
  {id:2, srt_id:1, run_time:   32},  // 32 seconds
  {id:6, srt_id:3, run_time: 5400},  // 1.5 hours 
  {id:7, srt_id:3, run_time:  600},  // 10 minutes
]
```

These run times show why I can't use a straight average.

- The first script taking 32 seconds to complete is not a big deal, but would show up as 600% of average.
- The third script running for 1.5 hours is a big deal, and there was probably an error that needs to be investigated
- However **150% vs 600%** gives the wrong impression
- Similarly, run 1 taking 5 minutes also means something bad happened, but it's not as big a deal.

### ***Question***

How can I factor in the average length, so the 150% of 1 hour looks ***more significant*** than the 600% of 8 seconds?

- And more significant than run 1 taking 3700% of the average 8 seconds

Edit: I'm hoping an industry standard exists, but if not, I guess I'm looking for a value from 0-100 that should measure how worried I should be about the time a run took. That could go outside of those bounds for more drastic situations.

Comment: Sounds like you're simply interested in the absolute difference (perhaps scaled)? I don't see anything in your question that warrants calculating relative difference.